# How do I break my while loop while still keeping it going?

Tags: python

I have made a program for a Tic-Tac-Toe game, and I want to make it so when you enter a tile once, its placeholder is filled but when you enter the tile again it will stop the while-loop. How would I do that? Here's my code:

```
userInput = input("Chose a tile: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.")
tile1 = 0
tile2 = 0
tile3 = 0
tile4 = 0
tile5 = 0
tile6 = 0
tile7 = 0
tile8 = 0
tile9 = 0
Stanford = 666
gameBoardMatrix = [
    ['1','2','3'], 
    ['4','5','6'],
    ['7','8','9']
]
while Stanford == 666:
  if userInput == '1':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [0][0])
    tile1 = tile1 + 0.5
  if userInput == '2':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [0][1])
  if userInput == '3':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [0][2])
  if userInput == '4':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [1][0])
  if userInput == '5':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [1][1])
  if userInput == '6':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [1][2])
  if userInput == '7':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [2][0])
  if userInput == '8':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [2][1])
  if userInput == '9':
    print ("You chose" + " " + gameBoardMatrix [2][2])  
  if tile1 == 1:
    print("Oh my, you seem to have broken the laws of physics. THE GAME IS ENDING! THE WORLD IS BROKEN!")
    break
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but it seems to me that you'll need to ask for user input within the while loop, and then branch off with a bunch of if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the occupancy state of the board in a variable similar to `gameBoardMatrix`, such as `is_filled_matrix`:

```
is_filled_matrix = [
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False],
    [False, False, False]
]
```

When the user picks a cell, you can update `is_filled_matrix` to reflect the change:

```
if user_input == '1':
    is_filled_matrix[0][0] = True
```

Later, in case the user gets to this cell that has already been filled, you can check its occupancy by looking at `is_filled_matrix`. This can be achieved by modifying your code as follows:

```
if user_input == '1':
    if is_full_matrix[0][0]:
        # The first cell has already been visited, we break
        break

    # The first cell has not been visited, we continue to play
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question, you want to exit the while loop as soon as someone chooses any of the 9 tiles twice.
For this, you need to hash the location(tile) and actions(click).
You can use a list or a dictionary to do the work.

> Using list:

```
lst = [False] * 9
while True:
    tile = int(raw_input())
    if lst[tile]:
        break
    lst[tile] = True
```

> Using dictionary:

```
d = {}
while True:
    tile = int(raw_input())
    if d.get(tile, False):
        break
    d[tile] = True
```